# Does $\sum (-1)^n p_n$ converge to $0$ for even $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, roots

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime number (starting with $p_0=0 , p_1=2, ...$). I computed the zeros of the polynomial 
$$
f_n(x) = p_nx^n + p_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + p_1x + p_0
$$ 
for different $n$. This polynomial has one real root $\tilde{x}_n\neq 0$ for $n$ even. Here are some example values:
$$
f_2(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_2=-0.666666... \\
f_{6}(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_6=-0.750523... \\
f_{12}(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_{12}=-0.802329...\\
f_{14}(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_{14}=-0.823575... \\
(f_{46}(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_{46}=-0.925623...) \\
(f_{96}(x) =0 ~,~ \tilde{x}_{96}=-0.963122...) \\
$$
The values appear to approach $-1$. This raises the question if
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{2m}_{n=0} (-1)^n p_n = 0.
$$
Is that true? How to prove it?

---

**EDIT TO CLARIFY MY QUESTION:** Take a look at the function 
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k x^k,$$
i.e. a polynomial of degree $k$ with prime numbers as coefficients. Task: Calculate the real roots of the polynomial for different $k$. For even $n$ we do not have any real roots. For odd $n$ we do have *one* real root $x_0(n)$, i.e. for any $m$ we have the root $x_0(2m+1)$. The value of this root $x_0(n)$ is given above and in the table below for increasing $n$. As you can see, it seems that the values are approaching $-1$ for increasing $m$, i.e. we have $$\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}x_0(2m+1) = -1.$$
That is, for $m\rightarrow \infty$ we would have $f_{2m+1}(-1) = 0$ or
$$
\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}f_{2m+1}(-1) = 0
$$
Now my question is the following: Does the root of a prime polynomial with odd degree tends to be $-1$ for increasing degree?

---

Ok, since this question is on hold and I can't write a comment or answer properly to this question, here's my answer to your problem:

It's not true! Look at this the following way:
$$f_{2m}(-1)=\sum^{2m}_{n=0} (-1)^n p_n=\sum^{2m}_{n=1} (-1)^n p_n=\sum^{m}_{n=1} p_{2n}-p_{2n-1}\geq m$$
since $p_0=0$ and $p_{2n}-p_{2n-1}\geq 1$ for all $n$. So obviously the alternating sum over $2m$ primes diverges! The pattern you noticed would imply
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \tilde{x}_{2m}=-1$$
I don't checked if it's true, but I think it is.

Another fact is obviously $f_{2m}(\tilde{x}_{2m})=0$ since $\tilde{x}_{2m}$ is a root of exactly this polynomial. But even if the above limit of the roots is correct, here is where it breaks:
$$0=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_{2m}(\tilde{x}_{2m})$$
$$\neq$$
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{2m}(\tilde{x}_{2k})=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_{2m}(\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \tilde{x}_{2k})=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_{2m}(-1)=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum^{2m}_{n=0} (-1)^n p_n=\infty$$
**The mistake made is in splitting one limit in two independent limits.**

Comment: The series's sequence doesn't converge to zero...

Comment: As stated, that limit does not exist.  But there might be a non-standard notion of convergence that you can use to "sum" the divergent series.

Comment: This is a companion of previous comments, you can see the code `sum (-1)^(n+1)prime(n), from n=1 to 100` in [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) with the purpose to know how are partial sum like the partial sums of your series.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66259/abel-summation-of-the-alternating-series-of-primes) is a discussion of at least one alternate notion of summation.  Note:  I haven't gone through the posted claims so I have no idea if any of them are accurate or terribly helpful.

Comment: @Lucas I think you miss something important... I calculate the sum for odd $n$! Similarly the series $\sum^\infty (-1)^n$ diverges but $\sum^N (-1)^n$ for $N$ even converges (always stays $0$).

Comment: @DonAntonio Since the series I am talking about is not alternating, but monotonically decreasing (see data), does that mean it diverges and becomes infinitely negative?

Comment: The series won't converge anyways - note that $p_{2n+2}-p_{2n+3}\leq -1$, so increasing the index of summation by two, the sum will decrease at least by $1$, hence it will tend to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Fabian I can't understand how you got that data. The series looks to me as $$0-2+3-5+7-9+\ldots$$Either you meant something else or I'm misunderstanding something big time...You seem to be referring to a polynomial $\;f\;$ , I'm talking about your **series** not converging.\

Comment: This is a variation of your series of prime numbers (thus this commment isn't related to your question). From the form of your numeric series involving prime numbers I believe that one can to define a variation of the so-called MRB constant, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MRBConstant.html), that are the two limit points of the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k (p_k)^{1/k}$ as $n\to\infty$. If it is interesting to you see the code `sum (-1)^(k) prime(k)^(1/k), from k=1 to 500`  using Wolfram Alpha online calculator. I hope don't disturb, I add this if you want to explore it